# problem; on inserting data gotten from my sign up into my database up form

Tags: forms, datatable, sql-insert

I tried to insert my values into the the database using $sql = "Insert into subscribe(id , name, email) values ( null, '$name', '$email')"
it did not work

i tried to insert
if(isset($_POST[submit-btn]){

$name = $_POST['name']
$email = $_POST['email']

$sql= INSERT INTO subscribe (id, name, email) VALUES (null, '$name', '$email'
}